# What is going on with my user and max date query?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

OK query below.   Hitting about a half million rows and I am trying to grab the last time a user (uid) touched a page on our system denoted by LogDate.   I have used this query quite a few times but applying it to a bigger table seems to cause issues.   Let me review.

- Keeping query is I can only grab about 8k rows or my query will just lock up - not getting much in logs.
- If I limit to 1000 it takes 2 seconds.   If I change it to 2k it takes 77 seconds.   8k takes about 88 seconds.   After that... nothing.
- If I take out the Distinct part it is obviously faster.   However I still can't grab the rows I need so it doesn't matter.    I have tried adjusting Innob memory settings which seems to have zero effect.

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>   `t1`.`uid`,
>   `t1`.`LogDate` AS `touchdate`
> FROM
>   (
>       `ref_source_page_log_report` `t1`
>       LEFT JOIN `ref_source_page_log_report` `t2` ON (
>           (
>               (`t1`.`uid` = `t2`.`uid`)
>               AND (
>                   (
>                       `t1`.`LogDate` < `t2`.`LogDate`
>                   )
>                   OR (
>                       (
>                           `t1`.`LogDate` = `t2`.`LogDate`
>                       )
>                       AND (`t1`.`uid` < `t2`.`uid`)
>                   )
>               )
>           )
>       )
>   )
> WHERE
>   isnull(`t2`.`uid`)
> LIMIT 10000
> ```

Comment: If you are tracking by each uid, what is the purpose of ``t1`.`uid` < `t2`.`uid``? Is there a reason why `MAX(LogDate)` grouped by uid won't work for your scenario?

Comment: @topshot the pattern the OP has used is a typical MySQL-ism for this type of problem

Comment: It seems to me that you have a typo in the bracketing.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Interesting. Found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17038667/4438429) of this, but would it be as efficient for large tables? Also, is the `DISTINCT` really needed?

Comment: @topshot  Look like that approach was used but with wrong conditions - `t1.uid < t2.uid` is used instead of `t1.id < t2.id`

Comment: Don't you need `ORDER BY uid, LogDate` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to rid of the excessive parentheses and backticks so I've got the next query:

```
  SELECT 
    t1.uid,
    t1.LogDate AS touchdate
  FROM      ref_source_page_log_report AS t1
  LEFT JOIN ref_source_page_log_report AS t2 
         ON t1.uid = t2.uid 
        AND ( t1.LogDate < t2.LogDate OR
            ( t1.LogDate = t2.LogDate AND t1.id < t2.id ))
                 -- Here was the problem: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (uids instead of ids)
  WHERE t2.uid IS NULL
  LIMIT 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple problems with the query.

- When `LEFT JOIN` does not find a matching row in the 'right' table it pretends there is a row but with all `NULLs`.  So any missing rows satisfy the `WHERE`!  I don't think you wanted that.  See if you get better results with `JOIN`.
- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is mostly 'wrong'.  Don't you need `ORDER BY uid, LogDate`?  (And I don't know whether it should be on t1 or t2.)

Based on "grab the last time a user (uid) touched a page on our system denoted by LogDate", the query is simply:

```
SELECT uid, MAX(LogDate) AS touchdate
    FROM excessively_long_table_name
    GROUP BY uid
    ORDER BY ????
    LIMIT 10000;
```